# c# Достать html код поу URL. HTTPS get запрос

Tags: c#, html, get, https

Есть некий https урл.

Например https://www.virustotal.com/en/domain/top.list.ru/information/

Мне нужно достать его html соурс. Без подгрузки картинок, цсс и подобного. Просто хтмл код.

Я испробовал все способа которые советуют на забугорном стековерфлоу, но все они возвращают пустую строку для https, почему-то. (На http не проверял ни один из вариантов, но судя по количеству плюсов на ответах -- c http работает нормально.)

Пробовал так же задавать вручную хеадеры вроде UserAgent. Результат тот же -- возвращает пустую строку.

Пример того что пробовал:

```
public static string GetHtmlFromUrl(string url)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            return webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }
```

и

```
public static string GetHtmlFromUrl(string url)
        {
            if (url.Length > 0)
            {
                Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
                // Create a 'HttpWebRequest' object for the specified url. 
                HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
                // Set the user agent as if we were a web browser
                myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0";

                HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                var stream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Release resources of response object.
                myHttpWebResponse.Close();

                return html;
            }
            else { return "NO URL"; }
        }
```

Comment: Зачем парсить html? У сайта есть официальный api: https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/

Comment: @PashaPash потому, что вопрос касается не только сайта  virustotal, а и других сайтов у которых нету своего API. Это был пример. Хотя в моем случае не факт что в АПИ есть метод который выдает нужную мне информацию. По крайней мере я его не нашел :)

Comment: Retrieving domain reports по ссылке выше - не он? А вопрос вроде бы касается конкретного сайта - ведь толькн на vt есть какое-то странное ограничение по заголовкам для https. на других сайтах - свои особенности.

Comment: Там написано "например" :) В целом меня интересовал вопрос относительно других сайтов тоже т.к. с проблемой ставлкивался не раз. Просто в другие разы обходил не совсем правильным путем)

Comment: тянуть данные с сайтов парсингом html - это уже не совсем правильный путь :)

Comment: А есть другие способа тянуть данные с сайтов окроме парсинга хтмл-а? За отсутствия API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что сайт дествительно возвращает пустую строку. Смотрите же сниффер - там Content-Length: 0.

А значит ему не нравится запрос и нужно больше разных хидеров, чтобы вас не принимали за бота. Например вот так

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");
        webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
```

уже возвращает контент.